# How to get first derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My question is to find the first derivative using product and/or quotient rule

$$f(x) = {(x^2+1)(x^2-2) \over 3x+2}.$$

The solution to the problem is:
 $$f'(x) = {[(2x)(x^2-2)+(x^2+1)(2x)](3x+2)-(3)[(x^2+1)(x^2-2)] \over (3x+2)^2}.$$

I'm having problems getting the same solution would someone be able to help me by showing me the correct way of getting the first derivative of this question

Comment: Do you know the quotient rule and the Leibniz (or product) rule?

Comment: Yes but is f(x) = (x^2+1)(x^2-2) and g(x)=(3x+1)

Comment: @HardeepChohanHarry You have a ratio f/g and f is a product, thus you have to combine the quotient rule with the product rule, let try and show your work.

Comment: If you're really lazy, logarithmic differentiation would seem like the fastest thing to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let apply the following

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)\cdot g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

with
$$f(x)=p(x)\cdot q(x) \implies f'(x)=p'(x)\cdot q(x)+p(x)\cdot q'(x)$$

Comment: Thank you I was able to get the same answer as the solution now!

Comment: @HardeepChohanHarry That's very good! You have only to practice to easily recognize these patterns! Bye and good work.

Answer (score 2):

When you have expressions which just contains products, quotients and powers, logarithmic differentiation makes life easier.

For your case
$$f = {(x^2+1)(x^2-2) \over 3x+2}\implies \log(f)=\log(x^2+1)+\log(x^2-2)-\log(3x+2)$$ Differentiate both sides
$$\frac{f'}f=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}+\frac{2x}{x^2-2}-\frac 3{3x+2}=\frac{9 x^4+8 x^3-3 x^2-4 x+6 }{(x^2+1 )(x^2-2 ) (3x+2 ) }$$
Now 
$$f'=f \times \frac{f'}f={(x^2+1)(x^2-2) \over 3x+2}\times \frac{9 x^4+8 x^3-3 x^2-4 x+6 }{(x^2+1 )(x^2-2 ) (3x+2 ) }$$ Now, simplify.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't like differentiating fractions, the following uses just the product rule once:

$$
\begin{align}
(3x+2)f(x) = x^4 -x^2-2 \;\;&\implies\;\; 3f(x)+(3x+2)f'(x)=4x^3-2x \\[5px]&\implies\;\;f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{3x+2}\left(4x^3-2x-3f(x)\right) \;= \;\ldots
\end{align}
$$